# Devise Functional Testing - no session data

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, functional-testing

I'm trying to get my functional tests working again after installing devise into my app. The app still works flawlessly, but for some reason after I use "sign_in @user" the data is in the session, but after I attempt something like "get :index", the devise (warden) session data is no longer there

```
test "should get index" do
  @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
  session[:session_id] = 4
  session['warden.user.user.key'] = sign_in @user
  puts session
  get :index
  puts session
  assert_response :success
  assert_not_nil assigns(:departments)
end
```

I manually set the session id and 'warden.user.user.key', but session_id was there in the second puts session, but not 'warden.user.user.key'. Regardless of whether I call "sign_in @user", it always redirects with a "You need to sign in or sign up before continuing" alert

EDIT -
I am using devise with mm-devise (since I'm using MongoDB and Mongomapper)

Thanks for the help - it turned out to be a problem with not clearing the database. The way that the users were created didn't overwrite each other, but it was ambiguous which User would be signed in.

Answer (score 0):

What is displayed for value of 'warden.user.user.key' in the first puts session?

Comment: {"warden.user.user.key"=>["User",[BSON::ObjectId('5031292354cf7f01c9000003')], "$2a$04$DHoE0bKefIExtmwWKRNYkO"]}, which is the same format as the session data when its running in development mode

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do something like I do here when I use Cucumber:

```
# This gives you the login_as(@user) method when request object is not present
include Warden::Test::Helpers
Warden.test_mode!
After { Warden.test_reset! }

Given /^I am an authenticated user$/ do
  @current_user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
  login_as(@current_user, :scope => :user)
end
```

...and cleanup your user factory to remove any credentials you may have.